# jQuery execute only the last event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a table with rows > 200.
I search for particular text in the table rows, if text exists (as a sub-string among the rows), I iterate over the rows and make them visible. If text does not exist, I make them invisible. I use input listener on text-field to detect the typed text:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //bind when DOM ready
    $('[name="token_search"]').on("input", function (evt) { //listener on textfield
        if ($(this).val() == "") { //if no text-show all rows
            $(".tokens-table tr").show();
            return;
        } else { //filter rows based on typed text
            $(".tokens-table tr").each(function (index) {
                if (index > 1) //do not hide first two rows
                    if ($(this).children()[0].innerHTML.indexOf($('[name="token_search"]').val()) != -1) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When a user types a text, the method will do sub-string search for every input event on > 200 items. When a user types too fast, or on low end device, this is leading to UI getting hanged. How can I modify the above code to execute only for the last input event on search field instead of executing on all input events in the queue? I mean as soon as the user types a new character, I want all the previous events in the queue to be cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very expensive part of your code is searching the dom on every iteration to get the value of the `input` that you already have available inside the event handler itself.

Do some caching of values and jQuery objects.

This snippet is the really expensive one:

```
 .... indexOf($('[name="token_search"]').val())
```

Instead :

```
 $('[name="token_search"]').on("keyup", function (evt) { 
      var  value = this.value;
      if (value)...
       ....

          .... indexOf(value)
```

This will remove your 100's of DOM searches for this same value

Similarly if you use `$(this)` more than once for the same `this`, cache it as a variable

```
$(".tokens-table tr").each(function (index) {
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.children()[0].innerHTML.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        $this.show();
     }
});
```

If these improvements don't help then you can also implement other solutions shown such as `throttling` or `debouncing` the time between searches using timers

Comment: Thanks! The tuning you recommended did add performance improvement !

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to use a timer to wait until the user has stopped typing for some set amount of time and then call your function. And you should also cache elements and values whenever you are going to use them multiple times in your code as charlietfl points out. The below should do the trick.:

Honestly though, if you're intent is to create a search box that filters a table, you might want to look into [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) which does an excellent job of filtering and so much more.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { //bind when DOM ready
   $('[name="token_search"]').on("keyup", function(evt) { //listener on textfield
     var $this = $(this);
     var value = $this.val(); // incorporated charlietfl's improvements
     // cache the value of the search input and this
     delay(function() {
       $(".tokens-table tr:gt(1)").each(function(index, element) {
         var $element = $(element);
         $this.val() == "" || $element.children()[0].innerHTML.indexOf(value) != -1 ? $element.show() : $element.hide();
       });
     }, 700); // waits till the user has stopped typing for 7/10 of a second, adjust as needed
     // 1000 = 1 second
   });
 });

 var delay = (function() {
   var timer = 0;
   return function(callback, ms) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
   };
 })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="token_search" id=""><br><br>
    
    <table class="tokens-table">
        <tr>
            <td>unfilterable row</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>unfilterable row</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>four</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>three</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>three</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: 700 is a suitable value for ms for most users

Comment: I checked out Data Tables. It sure is smooth. Thanks!